# Javascript how to make sure JQuery .append is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript function, which uses `.append` from JQuery. However it only works if I add `alert()` at the beginning of the function. I have found out the reason for this behavior is due to the asynchronous way AJAX works.

How can I make sure that this function displays the html as wanted?

```
this.printJSON = function(id) {
    //alert(id);
    $(id).append('<button id="#store">store</button>');
    for(key in params) {
          $(id).append('<p '...'</p>');
    }
};
```

my whole class, which is called this way:

```
params.parseJSON();
params.printJSON("#showdata");

function Parameters(parametersFile) {
    //private stuff
    var paramFile = parametersFile;
    var params = {};

    //public stuff
    this.parseJSON = function() {
        $.getJSON('inputFileParametersJSON.txt', function(json) {

        for(var param in json) {
            for(var key in json[param]) {
                if(json[param].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    params[key] = {
                    filterIdentifier : json[param][key].filterIdentifier,
                    paramIdentifier : json[param][key].paramIdentifier,
                    param : json[param][key].param
                        };
                    }
                 }

          }
       });
    };

    this.printJSON = function(id) {
            alert("");
        $(id).append('<button id="#store">store</button>');
        for(key in params) {
                $(id).append('<p id="' + key + '"> filterIdentifier: ' + params[key].filterIdentifier + '<br /> paramIdentifier: ' + params[key].paramIdentifier + '<br /> param= <input type="text" id="' + key + '"name="param" value="' + params[key].param + '"/></p>');

                        //alert(params[key].filterIdentifier);
        }
    };
```

}

Comment: You will have to show us more of your code so we can see where this fits in your ajax calls since you seem to think that is the issue.  If you are operating on the results of your ajax call, then you must do that from the success handler of the ajax call, not from code placed after the ajax call (due to the asynchronous nature of the ajax call).

Comment: Where does the `id` element come from? Is it an element on the page? Is it loaded via ajax?

Comment: When are you calling printJSON?  Have you waited for the success function from the ajax call so you know the ajax call has completed?

Comment: How are you trying to call `printJSON()`?

Comment: You are calling `printJSON` before the `parseJSON` finishes. Include a callback parameter into `parseJSON` that will get called after the for-cycles. In the provided callback you can include code that is calling `printJSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jcm has said, you should be calling `printJSON()` from the response handler to enable it to work once the results of the request have been used to populate `params`.

**Here be monsters**

If you really need to wait for the result of an ajax post and can't use the result in a response handler (which is almost never), you can set `async` to false (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), **but** since JS is executed in a single thread, this will halt execution of the JS until the request is completed.

Since you are using `$.getJSON()` you would need to use the `ajaxSetup` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/ to change the behaviour of the ajax call.

Comment: Very bad to use synchronous ajax calls as it hangs the browser for the duration of the networking call.  I would NOT recommend this.  It's much better to change your code to work with an asynchronous ajax call.

Comment: Very true, OP's code should be in another function called by the response handler. The answer's been updated to reflect best practices, but I'll leave up as there are situations where an async request is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may need to re-evaluate the way your functions are being called. Do you actually need to call them seperately? I'd rename `parseJSON` to something like `getJSON`

```
function Parameters(parametersFile) {
    // ...

    var printJSON = function(id) {
        $(id).append('<button id="#store">store</button>');
        for(key in params) {
            // ...
        }
    };

    //public stuff
    this.getJSON = function(id) {
        $.getJSON('inputFileParametersJSON.txt', function(json) {

        // process results ...

          printJSON(id);
       });
    };

}
```

This way you can simply call `foo.getJSON('#someid')` and it will not append until the request has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that `.printJSON()` is called after `.parseJSON()` finishes parsing the data. This can be done by directly calling `.printJSON()` (see answer by **jcm**) or by addind a support for callback that will get executed when `.parseJSON` is done.

```
function Parameters(parametersFile) {
    var that = this;
    // ...
    this.parseJSON = function(callback) {
        $.getJSON('inputFileParametersJSON.txt', function(json) {
            for (var param in json) {
                for (var key in json[param]) {
                    // ...
                }
            }
            callback.call(that);
        });
    };

    this.printJSON = function(id) {
        // ...
    }
};

// ...
parameters.parseJSON(function() {
    // ...
    // you can use "this" as if you were in Parameters
    this.printJSON(someId);
    // ...
});
```